# Need to make individual jqgrid cells editable based on a certain value

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid and I want certain cells to be editable based on the value in a separate hidden cell.  So every row in the grid does not have the same config.  In other words, I don't want an entire column to be editable.

I put the code below in the loadComplete event for the grid.  I loop through each row and set the editable property on EstimatedCost and AverageSalePrice to true based on the hidden value ProductCatIndex.

```
var ids = $('#' + jqgrid_id).jqGrid('getDataIDs');
var count = $('#' + jqgrid_id).getGridParam('reccount');

for (var x = 0; x < count; x++) {
    var rowId = ids[x];

    if (row.ProductCatIndex == 2) {
        $('#' + jqgrid_id).jqGrid('setCell', rowId, 'EstimatedCost', '', '', { 'editable': true });
    }
    else if (row.ProductCatIndex == 3) {
        $('#' + jqgrid_id).jqGrid('setCell', rowId, 'AverageSalePrice', '', '', { 'editable': true });
    }
}
```

I step through the code and see it running properly, however the cells are not editable.  I have cellEdit: true at the grid level but I do not set the editable property on the column as I am trying to set it dynamically in the code above.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you do this does not have any effect

I can recommend other way to do this.

The cell is not editable if it has a class 'not-editable-cell', instead that in colModel is set to be editable. See the [docs here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#cell-editing)

This way a cellattr function can be used, since it add attributes during creation. See [docs here too](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#colmodel-options)

Set the editable property to true and try with this code:

```
colModel : [ 
    ...
    { name : 'EstimatedCost', editable : true,..., 
         cellattr : function( id, val, rawdata, cm, rdata)  { 
             ret = ""
             if( parseInt(rdata['ProductCatIndex'],10) !== 2 ) {
                 ret = " class='not-editable-cell'";
             }
             return ret;
         }
     }
```

Do the same for the other field.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That is fabulous!  Can you please answer one more question regarding this?  When I click on a column header to sort, attributes that are assigned using the cellattr function seem to disappear.  How do I retain or reset the values after a sort?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used - Guriddo jqGid , free-jqGrid or jqGrid <= ver 4.7? What is your datatype parameter in grid options?

Comment: We are using jqGrid 4.4.4 and the datatype is 'local'.

Comment: This is very old version and it may contain some missing additions. It is no more supported. Please, if possible switch to the last of one of the supported: commercial [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net) developed from us, or [free-jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) which seems to be stopped.